# Yii how to count related models (getRelation with params)?

Tags: yii, count, parameters, yii-relations

I have a HAS_MANY relation called "relationName",

So I can get all related models using

```
$model->relationName;
```

or using

```
$model->getRelated('relationName');
```

I can also get a subset of relatedModels, by adding params

```
$model->getRelated('relationName', true, array('fieldName'=>'val'));
```

So, I will get a subset of all related models, which *fieldName* = "*val*"

**but how can I count them?**

This idea looks like bad one (because it will take all models and then count them):

```
count($model->getRelated('relationName', true, array('fieldName'=>'val')));
```

I need something which will finally build query with COUNT(), and return result.

Using STAT relation is also looks like bad idea (because I already described relation in code, why should I duplicate the description of relation?)

So, **is there any good solution to count related (HAS_MANY) models with dynamic params?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I had such models:
Product  (product_id)
Order (order_id, product_id)
OrderProduct (order_id, product_id)

Product model had relation

'orders'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Order',array('order_id'=>'order_id'),'through'=>'orderedProducts'),

My task was - to count each product->orders, without loading all orders models.

As Ross suggested, I created STAT relation

'statOrders'=>array(self::STAT,'Order',array('order_id'=>'order_id'),'through'=>'orderedProducts'),

Eventually when I called $product->statOrders, I got an exception CStatRelation has no 'through' attribute

[image]

Which means that if I want to make it work, I have to invent another way to describe relation between products and orders.. It's even worse than duplication.

Finally I came up with this workaround:

```
$c=$product->getRelated('orders', true, аггау('select'=>'CОUNТ(огdегѕ.огdег_іd) as order_id', 'gгоuр'=>'ргоduсt_іd'));
$count=$c[О]->order_id;
```

• No need to describe new relation

• It makes clean sql query:

```
system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT COUNT(orders.order_id) as order_id, `orders`.`order_id` AS `t1_c0` FROM `orders` `orders` LEFT OUTER JOIN `orders_products` `orderedProducts` ON (`orderedProducts`.`order_id`=`orders`.`order_id`) WHERE (`orderedProducts`.`product_id`=:ypl0) GROUP BY product_id. Bound with :ypl0='458739')
```

• You can dynamically add params:
    [image]

• By analogy you can count amount of products in orders (sum products quantity in each order):
    [image]

My current final solution:
    [image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be run as a COUNT() query, your best option is to use a stat relation.

`'countOfRelationName' => array(self::STAT, 'Relation', 'field', 'condition'=>'field = val')`

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure that there is no easy way to count without creating additional relation?